# put a Grid to the first item of a listbox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'd like to put a grid into the first item of my listbox, i dont just need a setter to change property but an entire grid (need add a headband with button and text).

I've serached a while...

I tried to put two listbox and "combine it" but it is not clean and it's make the ui bad.

```
<ListBox Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignListBox}"
        x:Name="first" Visibility="Visible"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0" MouseDoubleClick="LessonList_MouseDoubleClick"
        Background="{StaticResource Secondary}" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstLesson}">

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- <Border Margin="10" Height="160" BorderBrush="DodgerBlue" BorderThickness="1"> -->
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="249*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="22*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Image Source="{Binding thumbnail}" Grid.Row="0" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"></Image>
                <Viewbox Grid.Row="2">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{StaticResource Txt}" Text="{Binding title}"/>
                </Viewbox>
                <Viewbox Grid.Row="3">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{StaticResource Txt}" Text="{Binding style}"/>
                </Viewbox>
            </Grid>

            <!-- </Border> -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>

<ListBox Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignListBox}"
        Visibility="Visible"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="0"
        x:Name="LessonList" MouseDoubleClick="LessonList_MouseDoubleClick"
        Background="{StaticResource Secondary}" ItemsSource="{Binding lessonss}">

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- <Border Margin="10" Height="160" BorderBrush="DodgerBlue" BorderThickness="1"> -->
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="249*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="22*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="25*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Image Source="{Binding thumbnail}" Grid.Row="0" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"></Image>
                <Viewbox Grid.Row="2">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{StaticResource Txt}" Text="{Binding title}"/>
                </Viewbox>
                <Viewbox Grid.Row="3">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{StaticResource Txt}" Text="{Binding style}"/>
                </Viewbox>
            </Grid>

            <!-- </Border> -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel></WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

I tried to make a grid inside the grid and make it visible only on first item but the grid is not detected because the grid is to "deep".

I've found this post : [How to have first item bolded in ListBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159470/how-to-have-first-item-bolded-in-listbox)

But i dont think it is usefull because grid isn't a property.

I don't know what to try now.

Thanks !

Comment: Be aware that the header could be scrolled out of view when there are more items than what fits into the visible area of the ListBox. Better put the header above the ListBox. Or put it into the ListBox's ControlTemplate above the ItemsPresenter.

Comment: @TheLimitSlayer: What exactly is your question? How to display the `Grid` in the `ItemTemplate` for the first item only?

Comment: yes but not exactly, i'd like to keep the actual Grid for each items and make another grid inside it. the grid inside should be displayed on first item only.